# Sort sql rows by multiple factors but in proportion in php?

Tags: php, mysql, field, multiple-columns

How can I order rows in my mysql database by multiple fields in proportion?
In this sort of way:
Price : Quality : Weight : Height = 1 : 2 : 3 : 4
So the system values price less than weight for instance?
Am I thinking about it right or do you have a better idea???
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ORDER BY can have multiple columns - so, ORDER BY Price, Quality, Weight, Height would first sort by Price, then Quality, etc....  Is this what you want or are you asking something else?

Comment: Something like that but in some cases it will really help to only have something show up when it's atleast a bit balanced, not to big in one field and very small in another. Get it?

Comment: Still not quite following you.  But, if you need to sort on some sort of calculated value, you can do so in your selection and/or order by.  So, if I wanted to sort on the Price per Weight (assuming the weights are in the same unit), I could say ORDER BY (Price / Weight)

Comment: THank you, I think I search for ordering by calculated values in combination with other fields! Like ORDER BY (Price/Weight) ASC, ORDER BY Price ASC, right?

Comment: Yes, that looks valid.